# launch several scripts located in subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is my problem. I have a directory that contains multiple sub-directories. In each sub-directory, there is at least one script sh.

I want to do a script that execute sequentially all this scripts.

I am pretty new to linux.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it using `find` and `for`:

```
for file in `find . -type f -name "*.sh"`; do sh $file; done
```

Use can also store it in array and do it:

```
array=($(find . -type f -name "*.sh"))
for file in ${array[@]};do sh $file; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "*.sh" -exec {} \;
```

This is a shell command which, beginning in the directory it's being run in (specified by .), finds file names that end in .sh and then executes those files (the found file is substituted in the {}). The backslash prevents the semicolon from being expanded by the shell (here, bash).

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon. To help OP, please expand on how your answer works.

Comment: Edited per your suggestion, Politank-Z. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the top directory, run the following command:

```
for f in `find . -type f -name \*.sh`; do $f; done
```

The find command will locate all .sh files.  The output of the find command (a whitespace separated list of pathnames to the scripts) becomes the input to the for command.  The for command processes each input, assigning each entry to the variable f.  The "$f" executes each script.